# How to append a div that has other nested elements inside of it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to append a div that has a couple of other elements nested inside it on successful AJAX call. I'm trying to append something like:

```
<div class="comment-flexbox">
    <div class="comment-container">
        <a href=''>
            <img class='comment-picture' src=''>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="comment-info-container">
        <p></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently I only have this:

```
$('.post-comment').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var userId = $("input[name=user_id]").val();
    var imageId = $("input[name=image_id]").val();
    var comment = $("textarea[name=comment]").val();

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: urlComment,
        data: {
            userId: userId,
            imageId: imageId,
            comment: comment,
            _token: token
        }
    }).done(function(response) {
        var commentsCount = response.image.comments;
        $("textarea[name=comment]").val("");
        $('.comments-container').append('<div class="comment-flexbox"></div>');
        $('.comments-count').html("<i class='far fa-comments fa-fw'></i>" + commentsCount + " Comments")
    })
});
```

Any tips, pointers or documents on how to actually append more complex structures like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st: in the html code `comment-container` inside `comment-flexbox` and on `done()` you trying to append `comment-flexbox` to `comment-container`?? !! I don't know which is right

2nd: you can create a variable with the html

```
var AppendHtml = '<div class="comment-flexbox">' +
                   '<div class="comment-container">' +
                      '<a href="">' +
                         '<img class="comment-picture" src="">' +
                      '</a>' +
                   '</div>' +
                   '<div class="comment-info-container">' +
                     '<p></p>' +
                   '</div>' +
                 '</div>';

// to concatenate the variable you can use

'<img class="comment-picture" src=" ' + Image_Source + ' ">' +
```

> **Note:** take care about single and double quotes single>double>single... or double>single>double...and for concatenate
>   use the outer quotes

Comment: I have comments-container and comment-container. The comments-container contains all comments and the comment-container contains the stuff like the comment, the username of the author, the profile picture of the author. etc. Maybe it is bad that they're so similar.

Comment: ok @Bobimaru you can still use the `2nd` code in my answer .. so when you have `AppendHtml` variable you can then use `.append(AppendHtml)`