# Laravel 5.7 - AJAX post to DB not refreshing results in main page

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to get my AJAX to update the contents of my html after I submit my form. My form submits correctly, the data get's saved to the DB and it WILL display on my page if I refresh the page manually. I am using Laravel 5.7 and PHP 7.3.

What I want is when I submit my note, it saves to DB, and after I save the note the html part that displays my note should update with the content I just saved.

I will let you know I am very new to AJAX, and while I don't think its complicated its obviously something I need to learn more.

JQ:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
    });

    $("#addPatientNote").submit(function(e){                 
        e.preventDefault();
        var patient_id = $('input[name=patient_id]').val();
        var note = $('textarea#note').val();
        $('#addPatientNoteModal').modal('hide');

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/patientnotes",
            data: {patient_id: patient_id, note: note, time: time},
            success: function(data){
              console.log('Post Success '+ data.id);
              refreshNote();
            },
            error: function(data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("AJAX errorjqXHR: " + textStatus + ' : ' +
            errorThrown + ' : ' + data);

             }
        });
      });
    });
```

Partial View:

```
<div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
        <h5></h5>
        <small>Date: <span id="posted"></span></small>
    </div>
    <p class="lead" id="patient_note"></p>
    <small>By <span id="firstname"></span> <span id="lastname"></span> 
    </small>
```

Now on the main page, I also have this...  I added the refreshNote() to see if that would help, it doesn't lol I am pretty sure I am doing all of this incorrectly...
JQ:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        refreshNote();
    });

    function refreshNote(){
        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: "/patientnotes/" + {{ $patient->id }},
            success: function(data){                
                var posted = moment(data.created_at).format("MM/DD/YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
                var updated = moment(data.updated_at).format("MM/DD/YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
                $('#patient_note').html(data.note);
                $('#firstname').html(data.first_name);
                $('#lastname').html(data.last_name);
                $('#posted').html(posted);
                $('#updated_by').html(data.updated_by);
                $('#updated_at').html(updated);
                console.log('Success '+ data.note);
            }           
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to make another ajax request .. just pass `data` as an argument to `refreshNote()` function

```
function refreshNote(data){           
      var posted = moment(data.created_at).format("MM/DD/YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
      var updated = moment(data.updated_at).format("MM/DD/YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
      $('#patient_note').html(data.note);
      $('#firstname').html(data.first_name);
      $('#lastname').html(data.last_name);
      $('#posted').html(posted);
      $('#updated_by').html(data.updated_by);
      $('#updated_at').html(updated);
      console.log('Success '+ data.note);
}

// then use it in success function
refreshNote(data);
```

**Note:** 1st: id should be unique .. 2nd: this code will not run outside the ajax success *where data defined* because you'll get an error of `data is undefined`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however it still does not update the html upon posting a new note on the page, i still have to manually refresh the page for the new data to show.

Comment: @Dyasis what is the output of `console.log('Post Success '+ data.id);`

Comment: the ID of the newly created note, which is:  Post Success 59

Comment: I even added: console.log('refreshNote called - ' + data.note);  to the refreshNote function and it displays the note info correctly, so the data is getting to refreshNote, its just not refreshing the html... im at a loss lol  I am starting to think its something with the view page...

Comment: @Dyasis if you have a duplicated id's the code will append to the very first id on the document .. please be sure you don't have duplicated id's and be sure the id's already exists

Comment: Correct, won't be duplicates as the id is the primary and there won't be an ID already as I am creating the note, not editing. 
So not to have any miscommunication, when John goes to his patient page, there is a Bootstrap Card that will show a note if one was already created, if not it will show a create button, when you click that button it opens a modal page to enter the note, then saving the model form, it submits the ajax call and saves to the db, so upon that action, when the modal closes, the main page for the bootstrap card should "refresh" using ajax from the note just saved.

Comment: @Dyasis Ok .. let's try something like  `$('body').append(data.note)` it should append the note to the body .. if it works so you need to check the elements with the id's you're using .. if not work try to `console.log(data)` whole data and see you got all the outputs you need or not

Comment: $('body').append(data.note) worked, so I guess I need to check my id's and again sorry, you meant unique id's for those, I thought you meant for the DB lol

Comment: @Dyasis I think you need to take a break :-) .. Have a great day :)

Comment: Well, I give up lol, I changed the ID's to extremely unique ID's and it still doesn't show the text... so i am yet again at a loss...

Comment: @Dyasis you can read my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53860981/how-to-append-a-div-that-has-other-nested-elements-inside-of-it/53861063#53861063) .. make the variable with the html then append it directly to the element you need